# Show background photo only on non-empty page

Tags: backgrounds, double-sided

I'm using `book` class, in which I redefined the `\cleardoublepage` to show "This page is intetionally left blank" when the page is empty.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\relax\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node at (current page.center)
    {\large This page is intetionally left blank};\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

I also set a background picture using `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` (here I defined a conditional to decider whether to show the picture). Now I wish the background image does not shown on the empty pages. Can I do this by further modifying the definition of `\cleardoublepage`?

Below is a MWE.

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\relax\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node at (current page.center)
    {\large This page is intetionally left blank};\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\newif\ifShowBackground\ShowBackgroundfalse
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
\ifShowBackground%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center)
    {\Huge\color{red} BACKGROUND};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\fi%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.center)
        {\Huge TITLEPAGE};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{titlepage}

\ShowBackgroundtrue

\frontmatter
Some preface 

\mainmatter
Main text \blindtext[10]

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My instinct would be to build the background image into the page style rather than through the shipout hook. This gives more finally-grained control over where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DonHosek 's hint, the solution is to add the background picture in the pagestyle setting (here I use `fancyhdr`) but not globally in `\AddToHook{shipout/background}`.

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\relax\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node at (current page.center)
    {\large This page is intetionally left blank};\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

%%<=======================
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[C]{% Background picture added here
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.center)
        {\Huge\color{red} BACKGROUND};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%<=======================

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.center)
        {\Huge TITLEPAGE};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
Some preface 

\mainmatter
Main text \blindtext[10]

\backmatter

\end{document}
```